# Confused by Android Activity singleInstance launchMode

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have two activities A(MAIN) and B, there is a button in A to start B, and a button in B to start A.

Activity A :

```
public class A extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }   
}
```

Activity B :

```
public class B extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, A.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest :

```
<application>
    <activity
        android:name=".A">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".B">
    </activity>
</application>
```

(1) When I declare A as singleInstance in AndroidManifest and leave B as default, run the app, start Activities by this order : ABABABAB.... After many times, the task seems like this:

```
Task 1 : A
Task 2 : B
```

(2) When I declare B as singleInstance in AndroidManifest and A as default, do the same operation as (1), and I get this result:

```
Task 1 : A
Task 2 : BBBBBBBBBBBB...
```

**Question** : Why singleInstance work differently in these two scene ?

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: Can you specify what you whant to achieve, singleInstance is not for regular use its just for rare cases I think that the flag you want is "singleTop" instead of "singleTask" or "singleInstance"

Comment: @Eefret Only get confused about two different results above. Any idea ?